# How to pass filters to Wicket Data Provider based on user choise

Tags: wicket, dataprovider

I have created a DataView backed by a Data provider. I am attempting to find out how are we suppose to have the data provider filter the data coming from the database based on a filter set by the user. The user is able to select many options that will then be used to filter the data in the database, however, how is this usually done when the dataview is backed by a data provider? Do I pass in the filter to the data provider? Should I run the query first, store it in an ArrayList and then pass in the list to the data provider?

The wicket examples have a contact data provider, but it does not show how it would filter the data based on users input. Any ideas?

Let me know if I need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I have some sort of criteria object:

```
FooCriteria {
  String bar;
  boolean baz;
}
```

... that is configured in a matching panel:

```
FooCriteriaPanel(String id, IModel<FooCriteria> criteria) {
  super(new CompoundPropertyModel<>(criteria);
  add(new TextField("bar"));
  add(new Checkbox("baz"));
}
```

... and passed to the results panel:

```
FooResultsPanel(String id, IModel<FooCriteria> criteria) {
  super(id);

  add(new DataTable("table", new FooProvider(criteria)));
}

private class FooProvider implements IDataProvider {
  private IModel<FooCriteria> criteria;

  public FooProvider(IModel<FooCriteria> criteria) {
    this.criteria = criteria;
  }

  public void detach() {
    this.criteria.detach();
  }

  public Iterator<Foo> iterator(long first, long count) {
    service.getFoos(criteria.getObject(), first, count);
  }

  ...
}
```